# Plot size changing with number of tick characters

Tags: python, matplotlib

Whenever I plot using `matplotlib` the box depends on the number of characters. So, if you want to align two figures with, for example, different y-axis tick characters, the box size will change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_a = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
data_b = [10, 10.1, 9.9, 10.05, 9.95]
data_c = [0, -0.0005, 0.00025, 0.00045, -0.00015]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.semilogx(data_a, data_b, 'bo')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax1.set_title('fig1')
plt.show()

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.semilogx(data_a, data_c, 'r*')
ax2.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax2.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax2.set_title('fig2')
plt.show()

fig1.savefig('test1.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
fig2.savefig('test2.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The output gives me two figures that are not the same in size in terms of the box. This is caused by the fact that the y-axis ticks of `fig1` are different in size to ticks of `fig2`. The difference is not great but whenever I add it in a document and align them, it is visible and thus annoying.

- Is there a way to ensure that the aspect ratio (or rather the y- and x-axis) are independent of the number of decimals so that the box stays the same size?

I have tried to play around with the aspect ratio and also used the same `figsize` without any luck.

Comment: Remove `bbox_inches='tight'`, because that crops the figure and it seems that you want to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Other problems appear (but perhaps not in this example) if I do that. The only thing that happens here is that removing `bbox_inches='tight'` partially removes the `code`. It also cuts other things (not featured here) like the `legend`.

Comment: It would "remove" everything which is outside the figure boundaries. In that sense "remove" might be the wrong perspective here - it would instead rather "not include" those. Just make sure everything you need to show is within the figure.